# Attribute column admin product grid check if value is larger

Tags: product, attributes, price, grid

In the adminhtml Grid.php I added this column:

```
$this->addColumn('import_price',
            array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Import price'),
        'type'  => 'price',
        'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
        'width' => '80px',
        'index' => 'import_price',
        ));
```

That works great, but now I want to display an other column, that checks if the value of the default price is <10 (larger than 10) in comparison with the import_price attribute.

Or is there a better way to see if the default price is higher than 10 in comparison with the import price field?

How can we fix this?

Comment: You can use a field renderer to display the value, in the renderer you can then check if the value is difference is larger than 10.

Comment: @VladimirKerkhoff How exactly can I do that?

Comment: See my answer with code sample

Comment: @VladimirKerkhoff Thanks for your code! But do you also know the input for (your logic)? Because I can't get it done by checking if default price is $10 higher than the import price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a module I created for something similar. Keep in mind that some changes might bee needed to fit your needs.

The idea is to rewrite the product admin grid block (maybe there is an other way but I was able to do it like that).
So create a module called `StackExchange_Columns` (Sorry, I'm not that creative with names. Feel free to change it).

You need the following files:

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Columns/xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Columns>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </StackExchange_Columns>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Columns/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Columns>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Columns>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_grid>StackExchange_Columns_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid> <!-- rewrite the product grid -->
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Columns/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php` - the rewritten product grid.

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Columns_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        //add the import price column
        $this->addColumnAfter(
            'import_price',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Import price'),
                'type'  => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'width' => '80px',
                'index' => 'import_price',
            ),
            'price'
        );
        //add a yes/no column to tell you if the import price is with 10 or more bigger than the original price
        $this->addColumnAfter(
            'bigger_by_10',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Is 10 bigger?'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'index' => 'bigger_by_10',
                'options' => array(
                   1 => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Yes'),
                   0 => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No')
                ),
                'frame_callback' => array($this, 'decorateStatus')
            ),
            'import_price'
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _preparePage()
    {
        //add the import price to the collection
        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('import_price');
        //add a 0/1 flag to check if the import price is bigger than the standard price + 10
        $this->getCollection()->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
            'bigger_by_10',
            '(IF ({{import_price}} >= {{price}} + 10 , 1, 0))',
            array('import_price', 'price')
        );
        parent::_preparePage();
    }
    public function decorateStatus($value, $row, $column, $isExport)
    {
        $cell = $value;
        if ($value == Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No')) {
            $rowTitle = $this->getRowId($row);
            $cell .= '<script type="text/javascript">$$(\'#productGrid_table tr[title='.$rowTitle.']\')[0].setStyle({\'color\':\'red\'})</script>';
        }
        return $cell;
    }
}
```

clear the cache and now you should see your 2 new columns in the grid. One with the import price and one with a yes/no value that tells you if the import price is with 10 or more bigger than the normal price. You can even sort or filter by this column.

Comment: You are my hero! That works great! :) Is it also possible to display the entire grid line with a red color, when the value is No?

Comment: @Jelle. Yes it's possible. Take a look at how the cache columns are built and do the same. Look in the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cache_Grid` at the column `status`. You have this setting `'frame_callback' => array($this, 'decorateStatus')`. this means that the method `decorateStatus` from the same class will be used before rendering the cell. You get the value and row as parameter and your can add some markup around it if the value is 0.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I checked the Cache columns and tried to use this code. But that does not seems to work. It breaks down the page. How exactly do I need to modify the code?

Comment: @Jelle. I made some changes to the `Grid.php` file. Now your lines that have that value set to 'No' should be written in red. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That works great! :) But is it also possible to give the row background the color, instead of the text? So that we can see it better? :)

Comment: @Jelle change this `setStyle({\'color\':\'red\'})` to what ever styles you need in the `decorateStatus` method

Comment: Wonderful! :) Currently your code checks if the import_price is more than 10 instead of the price. Is it also possible to add a tax rule to this? For example we use 21% tax. Is it possible to check if the price is +21% and + 10?

Comment: Your questions spawns too many child questions. Next time, make your questions clearer. You have this condition `(IF ({{import_price}} >= {{price}} + 10 , 1, 0))` Feel free to change the condition to fit your needs. it should be something like this, but not sure `(IF ({{import_price}} >= {{price}} * (1.21) + 10 , 1, 0))`

Comment: Many thanks Marius for your help! :) Works like a charm

Comment: Marius, can you help me with one last thing? I want to display the difference in price between the import_price and the price after the value "Yes" or "No" in the column "Is 10 bigger?". So that the value of the column "Is 10 bigger?" will be for example "Yes (+13.00)" or "No (-2.00)". How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't think you can do that and keeep the filters. Maybe you should add a new column

Comment: If I want to add another column that does the oposit? That checks if the value of the import price is more than 20 bigger thant the price. So that we no if it is to high. How can I edit this code for that?

Comment: Actually I thought about it and you can add the price difference in the yes/no column. You can use the method `decorateStatus` and append to the value printed this `$row->getImportPrice() - $row->getPrice()`. And if you want a new column to check if the price is bigger by 20 just edit the condition `(IF ({{import_price}} >= {{price}} + 10 , 1, 0))` to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks! But by editing the condition, it does not add another column in the grid. How can I add the column that does check if the value is higher than 20? And if so, it set the column to yes.

Comment: then add an other column and condition the same as the one I added. I understood wrong

Answer (score 4):

To use the Renderer for showing a value in the column for a product add the following line to your addColumn array:

```
'renderer'  => 'My_Example_Block_Renderer_Import_Price',
```

Then add the renderer class:

```
class My_Example_Block_Renderer_Import_Price extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());

        if ([your logic] ) {
            return $value;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

To get a value from an other attribute from the collection in the grid you can use:

```
$row->getData('column_name');
```

Comment: Ok, so the ORM has it's perks, but trying to get a calculated field in via join or addAttribute is no fun. I mean, you should be able to do something like this: `SELECT entity_id, (grand_total - subtotal != tax_amount) AS oh_oh FROM sales_flat_order`, then there's no need for post-processing.

Comment: @Melvyn What entire code do you mean? Is that a better way to fix it?

Comment: Depends on the resulting query. Basically, the database can add a calculated column, like `(ABS(price - import_price) > 10) AS danger_will_robinson`. Then you can use that as boolean value. In theory, this should perform better and is cleaner in your Grid code. However, I gave up on figuring out how to get that in Magento ORM in _prepareCollection.

Comment: @Melvyn Do you know a entire solution to this problem? I can't get it fixed. Do you know the input for (your logic)?